# What's the easiest way to handle a string looking like a query string?

Tags: c#, regex, query-string

Note: It's **not** a question about `Request.QueryString["parameter"]`.

I'm going to get a string that looks like a query string, i.e. follow the pattern of:

```
String s = "alpha=&beta=something&gamma=nothing";
```

I'd go with regex but perhaps someone else can suggest a neater way to split up and pick out the values for the keys contained. Suggestions?

Ultimately, I'll need to map them to a `IEnum<KeyValuePair>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString`. 
From msdn:

```
// Parse the query string variables into a NameValueCollection.
NameValueCollection qscoll = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(querystring);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx

Comment: And then consider adding an extension method to the NameValueCollection to output as KeyValuePair. See example here http://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2009/01/27/query-string-extension-methods-for-systemuribuilder/

Comment: Yupp, that's it, I think. Just a question - why doesn't it give me a *Dictionary*? The *NameValueCollection* seems to be a type from the ages of .NET 2.0, right?

Comment: It's because the NameVAlueCollection can store multiple values for the same key. There are some good examples here: http://www.studyblog.net/2011/01/namevaluecollection-vs-dictionary/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Dictionary&lt;string,string&gt; d = s.Split('&').Select(x => x.Split('='))
     .ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => x[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var pairs = s.Split("&");
var keyvaluepairs = pairs.
                    Select(i => 
                    { 
                        var data = i.Split("="); 
                        return new KeyValuePair(data[0], data[1]); 
                    });
```

Comment: I think I wasn't clear. Sorry. I'm not looking for **some way** to resolve it. I'm looking for **a really neat way** to resolve it. Something like a class (already in .NET, nothing I need to create, because I'm lazy, hihi) that'd map my pseudo query string into e.g. *Dictionary* of *KeyValuePair* objects.

Comment: I guess it all depends on what you mean by *neat*. Anyhow you can create extension method out of it or create some sort of utility class which will give you `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair>` or `Dictionary` or whatever you want.

Comment: Actually, now that I see it, it **is** a neat method you suggested. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 1):

you can call `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString`

```
var nvc = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(s);
```